# Submit input not posted in Chrome, etc

Tags: php, html, forms, google-chrome, form-submit

Since the version 54 of `Chrome`, some of my web apps are not working. (They are running since over a year!!)

```
<form id="clientFrm" action="allClients.php" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="IDClient" name="IDClient" value="<?php echo ISSET($IDClient) ? $IDClient : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nom" name="Nom" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Nom) ? $Nom : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Prenom" name="Prenom" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Prenom) ? $Prenom : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Entreprise" name="Entreprise" value="<?php echo ISSET($Entreprise) ? $Entreprise : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Adresse" name="Adresse" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Adresse) ? $Adresse : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ville" name="Ville" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Ville) ? $Ville : '' ?>">
  <input id="cancelBtn" name="cancelBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel">
  <button id="saveBtn" name="saveBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Enregistrer</button>
  <button id="saveBtnAdd" name="saveBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="saveAdd">Enregistrer  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

In the `allClients.php`, I was testing the value of `$_POST['saveBtn']` and it was working very well until the latest update of `Chrome (v54)`.

Now, when I do a `var_dump($_POST)`, I don't see anymore the "`saveBtn`". Have you notice changes recently? What can I do? I've a lot of web apps I'll need to  change :(

Answer (score 0):

I try your code, work very well

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
<form id="clientFrm" class="form-horizontal form-label-left" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="IDClient" name="IDClient" value="<?php echo ISSET($IDClient) ? $IDClient : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Nom" name="Nom" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Nom) ? $Nom : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Prenom" name="Prenom" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Prenom) ? $Prenom : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Entreprise" name="Entreprise" value="<?php echo ISSET($Entreprise) ? $Entreprise : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Adresse" name="Adresse" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Adresse) ? $Adresse : '' ?>">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Ville" name="Ville" required="required" value="<?php echo ISSET($Ville) ? $Ville : '' ?>">
  <input id="cancelBtn" name="cancelBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Cancel">
  <button id="saveBtn" name="saveBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="save">Enregistrer</button>
  <button id="saveBtnAdd" name="saveBtn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="saveAdd">Enregistrer  <i class="fa fa-plus-square-o"></i></button>
</form>
```

Comment: You have the latest version of Chrome (v54.0.2840.11)? When you click on the button "save" (id="saveBtn") and you have the value "save" in $_POST['saveBtn'] ?

Comment: Yes, Version 54.0.2840.87 m
I got this when click the Enregistrer
array(7) { ["IDClient"]=> string(0) "" ["Nom"]=> string(1) "a" ["Prenom"]=> string(1) "b" ["Entreprise"]=> string(1) "c" ["Adresse"]=> string(1) "d" ["Ville"]=> string(1) "e" ["saveBtn"]=> string(4) "save" }